# Different users with different encrypted workplace?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, encryption, users

When installing Ubuntu there is an option to encrypt the workplace. Now for one user I would have an encrypted place. That´s fine, but what if I would like to add later a second user. For that user2 I also want an encrypted workplace, with a different password. I also want that these workplaces are separated - that means if somebody would get access to user1 the user2 should not have to worry about anything (also vice versa).

Is there a way to do so? Or is there something wrong with this idea?

Thank you!

Edit: Using Ubunutu 14.04 if this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add user's you would need to use the following command:

```
sudo adduser newuser
```

Once that is done, you would have to add a password for the newuser:

```
sudo passwd newPassword
```

I would recommend taking a look at adduser's man page to get a list of all the commands for adding the user so you can set it according to how you would like it.

```
man adduser
```

Comment: With using 'adduser' I can ensure that there is a separated workplace that is also encrypted and user1 don't have any access to that?

Comment: That is correct when you set the password that is. But again, take a look at the man page for adduser as there is plenty of options that it has available to customize your system. Also, take a look at this website if you want to look at other programs that encrypt a username/group: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/encrypt-home-folder-ubuntu-installation-linux/